# Not able to stop Service when Broadcast Receiver is registered in Service

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am having a `BroadcastReceiver` in a `Service`.

I am registering receiver in service's `oncreate()` method like,

```
final MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SOME_FILTER);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}
```

Then I have created a method to unregister receiver and stop service like,

```
public void stopService(){
    if(myReceiver != null){
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

But it **does not stop** the service. There is **no exception, no error**. Simply the service doesn't stop.

I have also tried it following way,

```
public void stopService(){
    if(myReceiver != null){
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}
```

By doing this the Notification of Service being run in foreground hides but service's `onDestroy()` is not being called.

> I also tried to put the code to unregister receiver in `onDestroy()` but after calling `stopSelf()` method `onDestroy()` is never called.

If I don't register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the service, everything works perfectly fine, service stops and `onDestroy()` gets called but when I register `receiver` then it doesn't stop.

Any ideas what's going on here?

**Edit**

This is how I am binding and starting the service

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

And this is `mConnection`

```
MyService myService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service){
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

Below is how I am unbinding the service and stopping it.

```
if(isBound){
    unbindService(mConnection);
    isBound = false;
}

myService.stopService();
myService = null;
```

Comment: How do you start the `Service` and where do you call `stopService()` (which btw is not a good name, since there is a method like it in `ContextWrapper` with different paramters). Also, do you bind the `Service` anywhere?

Comment: @ci_ I have added code to the question.

Comment: you are providing incomplete code,  what is playerService? why don't you post a working client and service code?

Comment: @pskink I think there is no use of posting whole (lengthy) code of the service and what service is doing has nothing to do with this issue. The point is if I register a broadcast receiver in service then it doesn't stop, without receiver it works well.

Comment: did the same and `onDestroy` is being called, see http://codeshare.io/7BcbK, you should also post the **minimal** version of your code that reproduces your problem, otherwise **nobody will help** you

Comment: @gprathour did my sample service work?

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much for your efforts, I have not tested it out yet. Once I do I will inform you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution of the same by hit and trial method.

I shifted the code to `unregister` the `receiver` in `onDestroy()` method and all worked.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(myReceiver != null){
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I think problem was occurring because I was trying to unregister the receiver before stopping the service.

Answer (score 0):

While a `Service` is bound, it will never be destroyed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().

While it is perfectly OK to have a `Service` that is both, bound and started, it makes for iffy lifecycle management issues (as you've just found out). *If possible*, you should decide if you need loose or tight coupling of your `Service` and then use a started or bound `Service` respectively. This will make your life easier.

Comment: I am first unbinding the connection and then stopping the service, check out in my updated question. And **everything works fine if I just remove the `BroadcastReceiver`**.